# Cookies cannot be set in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, internet-explorer-9

I have the following code in website1.com:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.cookie = "qwe=1";
    alert(document.cookie);
</script>
```

and website2.com contains:

```
<iframe src="http://website1.com"></iframe>
```

When I open the page website2.com in IE it alerts empty string  (if no cookies was set before).
Other browsers alert "qwe=1".

So the question is why and how to workaround this?

Comment: header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is about security in IE.

If you want allow access to cookies in IFRAME, you should set HTTP header as follows:

ASP.NET:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("p3p","CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"");
```

JSP:

```
 response.addHeader("P3P","CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"")
```

PHP:

```
header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
```

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are set with `document.cookie`, however they are not sent to the server (and therefore have no effect there) until the next pageload. I would assume that standard behaviour of `document.cookie` is to mimic this and not update the read value until the next pageload (in other words, setting `document.cookie` sets a cookie, but reading `document.cookie` gives the cookies that were sent in the request).

IE9 fixed a lot of issues present in older versions. And I mean a ***LOT***. This is most likely one of them. The workaround, I would imagine, is handling cookies yourself. Just as in PHP I have the function:

```
<?php
function setRealCookie( ... ) {
    setcookie( ... );
    $_COOKIE[...] = ...;
}
?>
```

In JavaScript you could create an object that keeps track of cookies for you, including updating itself when a cookie is set and so on. Something like:

```
(cookies = {
    data: {},
    init: function() {
        var c = document.cookie.split(";"), l = c.length, i, t;
        for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
            t = c[i].split("=");
            cookies.data[t.shift()] = t.join("=");
        }
    },
    read: function(key) {
        return cookies.data[key];
    },
    set: function(key,value) {
        document.cookie = key+"="+value;
        cookies.data[key] = value;
    }
}).init();
```

Then you can set a cookie with `cookies.set("qwe","1");` and read it back with `cookies.read("qwe");`.